# how do i install all requirments to run asp.net and IIS on windows 7?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-7, prerequisites

I am new to the asp.net environment coming from a Lamp background with php where i just install a package and everything gets installed. How does it work with asp.net ? is there one package that i install or is it a few things I need to get it going?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, solution you looking for called [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). It's great simple program which allows you to install everything you need to develop ASP.NET sites just in few clicks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need IIS installed, if some features are missing you can install them via Turn Windows Features on or off (Control Panel).
Then you also need an environment to create the asp.net application, like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping this link will helps you on [how to install iis in windows 7 system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx) , it will be automatically installed with microsoft visual studio ...

This link will helps you on how to [install visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx) in windows 7 OS